# VLAN Debian server interface configuration file

Tags: networking, debian, vlan

Problem: how to configure a Debian pxe server for VLAN usage.

Here at my office they added a VLAN in order to solve the DHCP issues caused by having 2 DHCP servers on the same LAN (Windows for clients and Debian for pxe booting
kiosk mode workstations)

My /etc/network/interface file is as follow (currently no VLAN added):

```
#loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
#IP SERVER
address 192.168.197.216
#GW
gateway 192.168.197.254
#NETMASK
netmask 255.255.255.0

network 192.168.197.0
broadcast 192.168.197.255
```

Now, in order to take advantage of the VLAN I suppose I need to do something.

My understanding is:

1. Install the VLAN package:
   apt-get install vlan package
2. Load the kernel module 8021q:
   modprobe 8021q
3. Modify the /etc/network/interface file by adding (pay attention I say adding ...in this example VLAN is tagged as 99)
   auto eth0.99
   iface eth0.99 inet static
   address 192.168.99.1
   netmask 255.255.255.0
4. Bring eth0.99 up:

   ```
   ifup eth0.99
   ```

My concern is about the /etc/network/interface file ...which in my opinion should be (after adding a VLAN 99):

```
#loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#before VLAN was created
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
#IP SERVER
address 192.168.197.216
#GW
gateway 192.168.197.254
#NETMASK
netmask 255.255.255.0

network 192.168.197.0
broadcast 192.168.197.255

#VLAN configuration added
auto eth0.99
iface eth0.99 inet static
address 192.168.99.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
vlan-raw-device eth0
```

My questions are:

1. Is the above procedure correct?
2. Is the /etc/network/interface file correct? (it includes both parts: before vlan was created and after that)
3. What about the default gateway (192.168.197.254), it doesn't change does it?
4. Since there's only one network adapter, is there any chance that things are not going work? Looking at my /etc/network/interface file, I feel
   puzzled. Actually there are two static IP...

Thanks a lot for any help.